# WEBi Date Variable

Tags: webi

I have a column with various dates and I need to only show data 3 days from current date - I've been able to show the date from 3 days ago but not able to link it to the column date.  Any ideas how I can get around this.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding correctly you want a way to filter down to the last three days. You cannot compare two objects in a filter. So you need to create a variable to see if the date is within the last three days and then filter on that.

I will show two approaches. First I need a **Three Days Ago** variable...

```
=RelativeDate(CurrentDate(); -3; DayPeriod)
```

I then can use that to create **Date Difference**...

```
=DaysBetween([Three Days Ago]; [Full Date])
```

And then **Within Last Three Days**...

```
=If([Date Difference] >= 0; 1; 0)
```

You can the filter on either of them to get what I think you want.

[image]